# Find EC2 instances that not equal to X - AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

I'm looking to find instances that is not equal to platform "Windows" and tag them with specific tags.

For now i have this script that is tagging the instances that are equal to platform "Windows":

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name' : 'platform', 'Values' : ['windows']}])
instances = response['Reservations']

for each_res in response['Reservations']:
    for each_inst in each_res['Instances']:
        for instance in instances:
            response = ec2.create_tags(
                Resources=[each_inst['InstanceId']],
                Tags = [
                    {
                        'Key' : 'test',
                        'Value': 'test01'
                    }
                ]
            )
```

I need help to add a block to this script that will add another tag only to EC2 instance that is NOT equal to platform "Windows".

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. Your `filter` lists only windows platforms. There is nothing else to add to.

Comment: I filter and list of my EC2 instances and if the platform is "windows" so add the XXX specific tags...and if the platform is NOT windows, add XXX specific tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Working for me. Also, Running create_tags inside the for loop, you are executing one API for each resource. Whereas create_tags supports multiple resource as input. Reference : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags

```
import boto3


#Initialize an empty list to store non windows instance IDs.

list_nonwindows = []

ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-east-1")
response = ec2.describe_instances()
instances = response["Reservations"]
for each_res in response["Reservations"]:
    for each_inst in each_res["Instances"]:
        if each_inst.get('Platform') == None:
          instance_s = each_inst.get('InstanceId')
          list_nonwindows.append(instance_s)

response = ec2.create_tags(
    Resources=list_nonwindows,
        Tags = [
            {
                'Key' : 'test',
                'Value': 'test01'
            }
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Works!!
Thanks Justin!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the filter and iterate over all the instances and inside the code add an `if` condition on the `platform` key.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="eu-central-1")
response = ec2.describe_instances()
instances = response["Reservations"]

for each_res in response["Reservations"]:
    for each_inst in each_res["Instances"]:
        platform = each_inst.get('Plaform')
        instance_id  = each_inst.get('InstanceId')
        if platform == 'Windows':
            response = ec2.create_tags(
                Resources=[instance_id],
                    Tags = [
                        {
                            'Key' : 'test',
                            'Value': 'test01'
                        }
                    ]
                )
        else:
            print(f'found non windows intance: {instance_id}')
            response = ec2.create_tags(
                Resources=[instance_id],
                    Tags = [
                        {
                            'Key' : 'nonwindow',
                            'Value': 'nonwindowvalue'
                        }
                    ]
                )
```

As per the  [API  docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Instance.html)

> The value is Windows for Windows instances; otherwise blank.

Code  is working correctly I  tested:

```sh
$ python3 describe_instances.py
found non windows intance: i-0ba1a62801c895
```

[describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

Response structure received from the `describe_instnaces` call

```json
{
    'Reservations': [
        {
            'Groups': [
                {
                    'GroupName': 'string',
                    'GroupId': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'Instances': [
                {
                    'AmiLaunchIndex': 123,
                    'ImageId': 'string',
                    'InstanceId': 'string',
                     ....
                    'Platform': 'Windows',
                    'PrivateDnsName': 'string',
                    'PrivateIpAddress': 'string',
                    'ProductCodes': [
                    ....
```

Comment: Not working, getting SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax on "else:"

Comment: @hightest was just indentation, I fixed the same.

Comment: Now it is adding the second tags 'nonwindow','somevalue' to all EC2 instances, windows and Linux, when it supposed to add those tags only to EC2 instances that is not Windows.

Comment: I'm getting output "found non windows instance: i-....." on all the instances, Windows and Linux, so only the second tag that in "else" is added to all the instances, when i have Windows and Linux EC2 instances.

Comment: @hightest you can check manually if there are any windows instance and try to do describe on it and see if it has the `Platform` attribute available. That's all I can say as per the docs I have read and APIs available. Only other possiblily could see if the value of the `Platform` attribute is small case, but docs show it is Camel case.